# Given any two sets $A$ and $B$ is it true that $A\cap B\times \{A\}=\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given any two sets $A$ and $B$ is it true that $A\cap B\times \{A\}=\emptyset$? I feel like it should be.

Comment: Is that $(A\cap B)\times  \{A\}$  or $A\cap (B\times \{A\}) $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is **false.**

Consider $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{1\}$. Then, $A \cap B = \{1\}$, but $A \cap B \times \{A\} = \{(1, \{1, 2, 3\})\} \neq \emptyset$.

Given any family of nonempty sets, their Cartesian product will also be a nonempty set.

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes to accept it says. However can you help me, given any sets $A$ and $B$ how can I find a set $C$ such that $|C|=|B|$ and $A\cap C=\emptyset$?

Comment: To do this, just choose finite sets $A, B$, and $C$ so that $A$ and $C$ do not have any common elements, and $B$ and $C$ have the same number of elements. For example, $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $B = \{4, 5, 6\}$ and $C = \{4, 5, 6\}$ works.

Comment: The sets aren't necessarily finite, is there another construction I can use?

Comment: If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, you can define $C = B$. But, if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, I don't think we can define $C$ in terms of $A$ and $B$. You might want to check with another post.